# Can we access overridden class function from the base class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Am stuck in a situation where I have a `let` variable declared & initialized in base class. I would need to pass a different enum in one of my other classes extending this base class.

So, I tried creating a class function in base class so that I can override and return a different enum type. But is there any way that I can access the extended class from base class ?

Created a sample code below to help explain:

```
class A {

    var string: String {
        get {
            // Is it possible to refer to the class type dynamically here ?
            // So that it would call B's printMessage
            return  A.printMessage("Hello")
        }
    }

    class func printMessage(message: String) -> String {
        return "You shall not pass !"
    }

}


class B: A {

    override class func printMessage(message:String) -> String {
        return message + "World !"
    }

}

let obj = B()
print(obj.string)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it like this:

```
var string: String {
    get {
        // Is it possible to refer to the class type dynamically here ?
        // So that it would call B's printMessage
        return  self.dynamicType.printMessage("Hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying with `A.dynamicType` :(. Although I am wondering how is it possible to access `self.dynamicType` in initializer before calling `super.init` Compiler always complains that `self` cannot be accessed before calling `super.ini` But not in this case ?

Comment: in your case you don't access dynamicType before init. You first initialize the object and then refer to a computed property and only then it accesses dynamicType